# How to send sms otp to mobile number after signup using django rest api

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have created django rest api for user sign up, with username, email, pasword and phone.Once user register with above details then user should receive sms otp and after we have to verify that otp for sign in, for these how to send sms using django rest api.

Below code is for sign up

```
class Signup(APIView):
    permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny]
    def post(self,request):
        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        response_dict = {"status": True, "message": "", "data": {}}
        try:
            username=request.data.get('username')
            email=request.data.get('email')
            password=request.data.get('password')
            phone = request.data.get('phone')

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
        user.save()
        ud = UserDetail(user=user,phone=phone,created_by=request.user.id)
        ud.save()
        response_dict = {"status": True, "msg":"Successfully Registered"}
        return Response(response_dict)
            # messages.success(request, "User account has been successfully Registered!")
    except Exception as e:
        response_dict = {"status": False}
        return Response(response_dict)
```

Comment: if you want send sms, you need use third party something like SMS BrandName

Comment: I want to send sms otp, once user register with mobile number, i have written api for username,email and pwd , but need to write api for sms. any reference

Comment: Third party will have api for you. You only need call it (like `requests.post`) and pass data like : phone number, content sms... This api depend your country working and third party you use.